# Javascript / Jquery modification needed to get things working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I have the following code:

```
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);   
}
var material = $("material");
var materialPrices = {"invalid": "from &pound;800.00","1": "&pound;1,200.00","2": "&pound;800.00","3": "&pound;800.00"};
var price = 0;
function update() {
    $(".block").animate( { backgroundColor: '#B5D8EA' }, 500);
    price = materialPrices[material.options[material.selectedIndex].value];
    document.getElementById('pprice').innerHTML = price;    
}
material.onchange = update;
```

basically in the line `$(".block").animate( { backgroundColor: '#B5D8EA' }, 500);` returns `$(".block")` is null when a value is selected from the dropdown select box. I have been told that it is to do with: function `$(id)` but have no idea how I should modify my code to get it all working, please can anyone help, my js is weak!!!

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, put a little more effort into your question by posting properly indented code.

Comment: Removing the `$()` function should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.. you have a conflict regarding the `$` sign.
`$` is a shortcut for `jQuery` and you overwrite that shortcut to a different function (`document.getElementById`). The bad thing is that you use jquery with the `$` shortcut even after you've redefined it.
The solution is either to rename your function to something else :

```
function getById(id) {
     return document.getElementById(id);   
}
var material = getById('material');
```

either use the full `jQuery` notation for jQuery objects :

```
  jQuery(".block").animate( { backgroundColor: '#B5D8EA' }, 500);
```

My oppinion is that if you use jQuery, you can get an element by id quite easy and you don'y need to add another function that takes care of that.  ex :

```
document.getElementById(someId) == $('#'+someId).get(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you have created `$(id)` function `$(".block")` will call that method which will look for elementById and wont find anything. So `$(".block")` is null and you are calling animate method on a null object which willl throw exception.

Try this

```
//Remove this method
/*
function $(id) {
                return document.getElementById(id);   
            }
*/
            var material = $("#material");
            var materialPrices = {"invalid": "from &pound;800.00","1": "&pound;1,200.00","2": "&pound;800.00","3": "&pound;800.00"};
            var price = 0;

            material.change(function() {
                $(".block").animate( { backgroundColor: '#B5D8EA' }, 500);
                price = materialPrices[material.options[material.selectedIndex].value];
                $('#pprice').html(price);    
            })
```

;

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery then you are overriding the jQuery `$` function by declaring.

```
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);   
}
```

You need to rename that function to something else since the jQuery implementation is a lot more advanced than what you have for your function.  You do not have support for getting elements by class name as you are trying to do with the `.block` call to your `$` function.

Answer (score 0):

`$()` overrides the jQuery alias "$".